# Pass by reference array inside hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, pass-by-reference

I want to modify an array which is located inside a hash in perl. However, I can't seem to pass by reference here. <strike>If the array is not inside a hash, it works fine.</strike> Here is my code:

```
%hash = (
    array1 => ['foo', 2, 'bar']

);
print @{$hash{array1}}, "\n";
changeArray($hash{array1});
print @{$hash{array1}}, "\n";


sub changeArray
{
    @array = @{$_[0]};
    $array[0] = "not foo";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./scrap.pl
foo2bar
foo2bar
```

Isn't `$hash{array1}` the reference to the anonymous array ['foo',2,'bar']?

Comment: *“If the array is not inside a hash, it works fine”* No, it doesn't. Your subroutine just modifies a local copy of the array that is passed. It doesn't alter the external array no matter where it came from

Comment: @Borodin Yep, my mistake. I had called the local variable the same name as outside the subroutine, so it appeared like the function was changing it.

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare every variable with `my`. That will protect you from the most simple mistakes and would have revealed the error here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your changeArray sub, you are making an array `@array`, from the arrayref contained in the hash,
so all changes will be for @array, which is going out of scope when changeArray is done.

try

```
sub changeArray {
   my $arrayref = $_[0];
   $arrayref->[0] = "not foo";
}
```

Comment: What's the `->` called?

Comment: `->` is the *infix dereference operator*. You can find the documentation on the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) manpage.

Comment: Of course, the out of scope part was not entirely accurate here, see comments above, that was assuming `sub changeArray { my @array = @{$_[0]}; ... }`. Which would seem the normal thing to do.